# Accidentally created symlink dhcpcd, how to remove it again

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation

I was setting up arch linux and accidentally hit enter after typing `systemctl enable dhcpcd`.

After that the console said

> Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/dhcpcd.service -> /usr/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service.

How can I undo what I have done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To undo this, disable the service:

```
systemctl disable dhcpcd
```

Comment: Okay I did that already, I thought I broke a bit more with it and had to do more to undo this. Thank you!